# TextFormField Validator: error border is not activated

Tags: flutter

When I press the button to validate the FormKey, the error border of TextFormField is not activating.
I want when I press the button, and if is not validate, show a red border.

Button OnPress:

```
if(this._formKeyEmail.currentState.validate()){
  //Pass  
}
```

TextFormField:

```
Container(
  width: this.widget.width,
  height: 50,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
    boxShadow: ThemeEffect.shadowInputField()
  ),
  child: TextFormField(
    onChanged: this.widget.onChanged,
    maxLength: this.widget.maxLength,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    keyboardType: this.widget.textInputType,
    controller: this.widget.controller,
    validator: this.widget.validator,     
    style: ThemeText.sign_up_input_field,  
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        counter: SizedBox.shrink(),
        errorBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: ThemeColor.flamingo,
            width: 1
          ),
        ),
      errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
      hintText: this.widget.hintText,
      hintStyle:  ThemeText.sign_up_input_field_hint,
      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      ),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: ThemeColor.white
    ),
  ),
)
```

Validator:

```
validator: (String value){
  if (!Validator.email(value)){
    return "error";
  }
  return null;
}
```

The 'error' label is shown, but the border Color.Flaming isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried errorBorder property?
Example:

```
errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    ),
```

Comment: Yeah. It is already inside 'decoration: InputDecoration()'

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please refer below code

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  MainScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode addressFocus = FocusNode();
  final _validationKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  int validateAddress(String address) {
    String patttern = r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.-]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);
    if (address.isEmpty || address.length == 0) {
      return 1;
    } else if (address.length < 10) {
      return 3;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        leading: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
        ),
        title: Text("Example"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Form(
              key: _validationKey,
              child: TextFormField(
                autovalidate: false,
                controller: addressController,
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                      r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                ],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                maxLength: 60,
                onChanged: (val) {},
                maxLines: 1,
                validator: (value) {
                  int res = validateAddress(value);
                  if (res == 1) {
                    return "Please enter address";
                  } else if (res == 3) {
                    return "Please enter minimum 10 characters";
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                focusNode: addressFocus,
                autofocus: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  errorMaxLines: 3,
                  counterText: "",
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 1,
                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                    ),
                  ),
                  disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 1,
                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                    ),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 1,
                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                    ),
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      )),
                  focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 1,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                  hintText: "Hint Text" ?? "",
                ),
              ),
            ),
            OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _validationKey.currentState.validate();
                if (addressController.text.isEmpty ||
                    addressController.text.length < 10) {
                  addressFocus.requestFocus();
                }
              },
              child: Text("Validate"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```